# Yeoman Or Roll my Own

Tags: node.js, code-generation, npm, yeoman, mean-stack

I'm working on a new MEAN stack app.  I have a lot of boiler plate code around creating and managing lookup type values in my mongoDB.  I estimate that I will end up with approximately 20 collections that will grow over time in my mongoDB.  Instead of hand code the CRUD operations for each "Collection" I was thinking about writing a code generator that would write the boilerplate code for my API and Client side controller, factory and HTML.   I already created the template for one of my lookups. Now for the 20 or so additional lookups I need to replicate the code just changing the database scheme for each lookup.

I feel like yeoman is too heavy for what I need to do and to opinionated?  Does anyone know of a tinplating  tool \ scaffolding package that I can use.  Basically I want to create the template file then just fill in the blanks based on my collection schemes.

I used the following package to template out the general idea.  https://github.com/thisandagain/generator Any thoughts on existing or favorite packages?

Comment: The following project takes the idea a step further: https://github.com/jspears/mers  Why not just create the scheme and let the API get "generated" on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following project:

https://github.com/jspears/mers

This will allow us to on the fly have a full CRUD API by simply defining the mongo scheme in mongoose js.

We have been using it for about a week now and it is workign great!